# How to get last inserted id in laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

how do i get the inserted  id in laravel 7 ?

```
if (!User::where('Name', $u['name'])->exists()) {
                        $user= new User;
                        $user->key =  $u['key'];
                        $user->Name  = $u['name'];
                        $user->save();
                        dd($user->id());
                    }
```

here is my error

```
Call to undefined method App\User::id()
```

Comment: This is simply a typo; `->id()` is a method, but `->id` is a property. You simply used the wrong one. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need the parentheses . You can use user->id only

If you use parentheses laravel searches for a function that is why you get that error.

After save laravel fills the object id parameter and you just need to take it.